# How do you replace a list of 5 0's with the first 5 even numbers? (python)

Tags: python

```
even_numbers = [0] * 5

for i in range(1,11):
    if i%2 ==0:
        even_numbers[i]=i
```

I am getting the error 'list assignment index out of range', although i'm not quite sure what that means.

Comment: why not create a list of 5 even numbers?

Comment: Try `print(i)` before the assignment. You will see that `i` gets bigger than 4

Comment: In the for loop i goes from 1 to 10, but your even_number list is of size 5, so can only be indexed from 0 to 4.  To fix: Init even_numbers with `even_numbers = []`.  Then in your loop use `even_numbers.append(i)`  Alternately use a list comprehensiion `even_numbers = [i for i in range(1, 11) if i%2 == 0]`

Comment: `range` can generate the even numbers directly: `range(1, 11, 2)`. There's no need to generate the odd numbers only to reject them immediately.

Answer (score 1):

"List index out of range" basically means that you are trying to access an array index that doesn't exist.

In your code, your loop goes up to 10, and you are trying to assign a number to `even_numbers[10]`, while your array only has 5 elements. Basically you're telling your program "give me the 10th element of this 5-element list", which does not make much sense. Your indices in this case only go from 0 to 4.

To fix your issue, try storing the current index in a variable:

```
even_numbers = [0] * 5
current_index = 0

for i in range(1,11):
    if i%2 ==0:
        even_numbers[current_index]=i
        current_index += 1
```

---

**Edit:** Alternatively, why not loop through even elements only, using the `step` argument of the `range()` function?

```
even_numbers = [0] * 5
current_index = 0

#will increment 'i' 2 by 2, i.e. i will be 2, then 4, then 6, ...
for i in range(2,11, 2): 
    even_numbers[i/2]=i
    current_index += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The message means that you are trying to access an element of the list which does not exist.

The list only has five elements with indices 0 to 4. Trying to assign a value to even_numbers[i], you will try to assign a value to all elements of the list in the range of 1 to 10. That's why you should change the indexing to even_numbers[i/2]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to generate the list of even numbers in the first place.

```
even_numbers = list(range(1,11,2))
```

If, for some reason, you already have the list, it's doesn't really matter what the original contents are if you are just going to replace them.

```
for i, _ in enumerate(even_numbers):
    even_numbers[i] = 2*i
```

or just `even_numbers[:] = range(1, 11, 2)`